# Highlight field content onFocus

Tags: silverlight, xaml, controls, expression-blend

Can anyone enlighten me to a way I can Highlight the content of an input field OnFocus preferably by XAML only?

So if a user bring focus to a field, it will highlight the string or whatever is in there so they can for example just tab to it, and replace the existing string as soon as they start typing instead of having to manually highlight and delete it first?

I've seen answers that require code, but wondering if there's a XAML only route? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I highly doubt there would be XAML code that is equivalent to the TextBox.SelectAll() method.

It should be as easy as attaching each TextBox's GotKeyboardFocus event to a single event handler like this.

```cs
private void TextBox_GotKeyboardFocus(object sender, KeyboardFocusChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (sender is TextBox)
        ((TextBox)sender).SelectAll();
}
```

```xml
<TextBox GotKeyboardFocus="TextBox_GotKeyboardFocus" />
```

Comment: Ya that's basically what I thought, just wanted to make sure nobody exposed some magical dependency property I missed in documentation to flip and make it available. Cheers, +1 for response and answered as its more or less what's required in my instance, thank you :)

Answer (score 3):

You can use AutoCompleteBox for this purpose and you won't have to write any code to acheieve this functionality. It already have this functionality and it will work as textbox too for you..

Let me know if you require any furter information.

Cheers!
Vinod

Comment: I was hoping there was a common Dependency property I could flip that I just missed in the documentation. Unfortunately it would require to much re-work to accomplish this method because of other dependencies already built in to specific controls, but will keep in mind for future use, thank you! +1 for response.